# Genymotion emulators are not shown in run configuration target tab

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I have created 6 virtual devices in genymotion. I configured the genymotion path in preferences also. I can able to run the non web applications through eclipse.

But when I need to run a web application, the emulator is getting connected to the internet.

When I try with run configuration tab option the installed virtual devices are not found.

Comment: Can you please explain what IDE you are using and the steps to reproduce the problem? Because for now the problem you encounter is not really clear.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna IDE. I need to automate a web service based mobile application.

When I try to run the application with normal Android SDK emulator it works well [I have made some changes in APN settings]

But the normal SDK emulator is very slow. So I am using the third party emulator genymotion.

I have installed the application in the Genymotion emulator and I made some changes in APN setttings but I couldn't able to save the APN settings.

When I try to use the mobile application to connect to the internet it fails.

Comment: Even in the default mobile browser itself I couldn't able to connect any website.
So when I have tried with the following in Eclipse

Run-->Run Configuration--> Right Click Android Application-->New

Then click on Target tab.

At the bottom of the window I was trying to use the additional emulator command line options.I thought that this could be the solution to overcome.If any other solutions are available, please post it.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to connect the Third party Genymotion emulator(Android Version 4.4.4) to the internet. I have entered the Proxy port mmc mnc in APN settings but it is not getting saved. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion Proxy settings for Internet Connection

Follow the settings in your virtual device:
1. Click Menu > System settings.
2. In Wireless & Networks, select Wi-Fi.
3. Click WiredSSID and hold it down for two seconds.
4. Click Modify Network.
5. Check Show advanced options.
6. In Proxy settings, select Manual.
7. Enter the proxy settings provided by your network administrator.
8. Click Save.